# I cant get my kivy widget to start at a position and move

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to kivy and can't get this widget to start at a certain position before it starts moving. In my kv file, my widget position is set to `self.pos`, and in my `fall` function, I use the `self.pos` to change the position of the widget and make it fall. The only is problem is that there's no way for me to add an origin position for my widget. Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy import Config
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, 
ReferenceListProperty,ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')

class TetrisGame(GridLayout):
    block1= ObjectProperty(None)



class Block1(Widget):
    vel_x = NumericProperty(0)
    vel_y = NumericProperty(-1)
    position = ReferenceListProperty(vel_x,vel_y)
    def fall(self, pos):
        self.pos =  Vector(self.position) + self.pos

class TetrisApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = TetrisGame()
        block = Block1()
        Clock.schedule_interval(block.fall, 1/60)
        return block

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TetrisApp().run()
```

And the .kv:

```
<Block1>:
canvas:
    Rectangle:
        size: root.width/5, root.height/20
        pos: self.pos
```

How might I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I will point out the errors of your code, `TetrisGame` is a class that is useless because in your case you only assign it to a local variable: `game = TetrisGame()`, this will be deleted when you finish running `build()` On the other hand, block is returned so that its scope increases.

Another possible error is that you are thinking that when you put:

```
size: root.width / 5, root.height/20
```

You are not changing the size of the widget, you are only painting a small part of the widget, what returns build is the window that you are painting a part of the window, what you must do is create another widget that is the window and in it, add as a child to the block. You must set the size in the constructor.

Going to the main problem, the position in kivy as opposed to the convention is relative to the bottom-left point, and up are y+ and for the right x+.

The solution is to obtain the size of the window using Window.

***.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy import Config
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window


Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')


class Block1(Widget):
    vel_x = NumericProperty(0)
    vel_y = NumericProperty(-1)
    position = ReferenceListProperty(vel_x,vel_y)
    def fall(self, _):
        self.pos =  Vector(self.position) + self.pos

class BackGround(Widget):
    pass

class TetrisApp(App):
    def build(self):
        background = BackGround()
        block = Block1(pos=(0, Window.height), size=(Window.width/4, Window.height/20))
        background.add_widget(block)
        Clock.schedule_interval(block.fall, 1/60)
        return background

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TetrisApp().run()
```

***.kv**

```
<Block1>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: root.size
            pos: self.pos
```

**Note:**

**You should not use GridLayout**, you should only use GridLayout when you want to place several widgets in the form of a grid, and in your case it is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't add the .kv for the TetrisGame because for the problem I'm facing, it'll be redundant. Your answer still explains and fixes my problem. Thank You

Comment: @user10112707 If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that's the best way to thank

Answer (score 0):

## Python code

1. Add import statements: `from kivy.graphics import Rectangle` and `from kivy.core.window import Window`
2. Set the starting position for the block, `block = Block1(pos=(0, Window.height))`
3. Add the block to the Root widget, `game.add_widget(block)`
4. Return the root widget, `return game`
5. Implement methods to update or remove the instructions you have added to a canvas
6. Add `dt` (delta-time) as an argument to `fall()` method.

### Note

*If `dt` (delta-time) is not in the argument list, we will encounter,*

`TypeError: fall() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

*Therefore, whenever we schedule a function using [Kivy Clock](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html), we have to include `dt` as an argument.*

*If we want to schedule a function that doesn’t accept the `dt` argument, we can use a lambda expression to write a short function that does not accept `dt`.*

## kv file

1. Give color to the block

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy import Config
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')

from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window


class TetrisGame(GridLayout):
    block1 = ObjectProperty(None)


class Block1(Widget):
    vel_x = NumericProperty(0)
    vel_y = NumericProperty(-1)
    position = ReferenceListProperty(vel_x,vel_y)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Block1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

        self.bind(pos=self.update_rect)
        self.bind(size=self.update_rect)

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size

    def fall(self, dt):
        self.pos = Vector(self.position) + self.pos


class TetrisApp(App):

    def build(self):
        game = TetrisGame()
        block = Block1(pos=(0, Window.height))
        game.add_widget(block)
        Clock.schedule_interval(block.fall, 1/60)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TetrisApp().run()
```

### tetris.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<Block1>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1    # red color block
        Rectangle:
            size: root.width/5, root.height/20
            pos: self.pos
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]
[image: Img03]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Another little question though for the `fall` module. Why did you include `dt` as an argument and not use it within the module.

Comment: If we remove `dt` (delta-time) from the argument list, we will encounter, `TypeError: fall() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. Therefore, whenever we schedule a function using `Clock`, we have to include `dt` as an argument. If we want to schedule a function that doesn’t accept the `dt` argument, we can use a lambda expression to write a short function that does not accept `dt`. [Kivy Clock documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html)

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, feel free to up vote and/or accept it, as you see fit. Thank you